# Can't install SDK with the message "done nothing installed"!

Tags: android, windows, sdk, installation

I have downloaded the Android SDK and I get this message in the SDK manager:

> "done nothing installed".

In the start where the program detect JDK I have:

> Location: C:\Program Files(86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe

**About my system:**

- I'm using Windows 7 and the JDK version 1.7.
- I'm running as an administrator.

*I've selected Android 2.2 up to Android 4.1 in the Android SDK manager.*

What can be wrong?

Comment: Please at least give some details about what version the SDK you're trying to install, what version of Windows, etc., etc. Also, there are tags for the android SDKs eg `Android-SDK-2.1`

Comment: OK sorry. I have Windows 7 and JDK version 1.7. I selected Android 2.2 up to Android 4.1 in the Android sdk manager.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the **SDK Manager** manually from Windows Start menu?  If yes, I had had problems installing updates receiving **nothing installed** until I ran **SDK Manager** using **Run as administrator**.  I also received error messages related to **access denied** on directory `c:\Program Files\Andriod\android-sdk\temp`.

Using **Run as administrator** worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I have windows 8, and when I searched `Android SDK Manager` through the file explorer, nothing came up. What do I do? I have the SDK manager through Android Studio...Please let me know.